# Android StopWatch : Milliseconds with two digit

Tags: android, runnable, stopwatch

I have successfully implement stopwatch, but i am not getting proper milliseconds with two digit like this mm:ss.**SS** 02:54.**12**, my code is

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        timeMill=timeMill+100;
        updateTime(timeMill);
        stopWatchHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};



    private void updateTime(long updatedTime) {
       //I want to convert this updateTime to Milliseonds like two digit 23
}
```

i have also try this  `final int mill = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);` but this is always getting 10, 20, 30...etc but i want to get 10,11,12,13..so on, if you have any idea about it plz help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing by 100ms. You need to increment by 10ms and post the runnable with a delay of 10ms. You can format the long using SimpleDateFormat.

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        timeMill += 10;
        updateTime(timeMill);
        stopWatchHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
    }
};

private void updateTime(long updatedTime) {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SS");
    String displayTime = format.format(updatedTime);
    // Do whatever with displayTime.
}
```

Be aware that this relies on the delay time of the Handler as a timer. Each repetition will introduce a tiny error. These errors may add up over time, which isn't desirable for a stopwatch.

I would store the time when the stopwatch is started, and calculate elapsed time from that each update:

```
startTime = System.nanoTime();
//Note nanoTime isn't affected by clock or timezone changes etc

private Runnable updateTimerThread = Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long elapsedMiliseconds = (System.nanoTime() - startTime()) / 1000;
        updateTime(elapsedMiliseconds);
        stopWatchHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am not getting proper milisecond for using this i am getting like this 30:00.70, 30:00.80, but i want like 30:00.71, 30:00.72 this

Comment: your increment is 100ms. Use 10ms instead

Comment: my stopwatch will be very slow

Answer (score 1):

```
            timeMill=timeMill+100;
            updateTime(timeMill/100);
            stopWatchHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
```

Comment: are you get any issue by my code because it's working in my end.

Answer (score 0):

use stopWatchHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);

Comment: then my stopwatch will be very slow

Answer (score 0):

```
stopWatchHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
timeMill=timeMill+100;

100ms = 0,1s  
10ms = 0,01s
```

You are updating every tenth second of your timer.

Comment: i am not getting what are you talking?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you update the `stopwatch` every tenth second in this code `stopWatchHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);` so it counts like: `0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ...`

You should change it to:
`stopWatchHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);`